# Is there a way to make a JButton disabled until the user puts in a specific word?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a text adventure game that includes puzzles in every room. I have direction buttons to go to the next rooms, but I want the buttons to display a message if they haven't answered the question correctly yet. When they answer it then the game will show them which way they can go and the buttons will work. Is there anyway to do this?

I tried doing this, but the only way this works is if they type the answer and leave it in the textfield instead of typing enter. I don't want that though.

```
private void northBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    if(!playerInput.getText().equals(currentRoom.getAns()))
    {
        gameScreen.append("\nThe doors are locked until you answer the puzzle.");
    }
    else 
    {
       String direction = "north";
        Room nextRoom = currentRoom.getExits(direction);

        if(nextRoom == null)
        {
            gameScreen.append("\n There is not an exit that way\n");
        }
        else
        {
            currentRoom = nextRoom;
            gameScreen.append("\n" + currentRoom.getLongDescription());
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, don't know why I thought this was javascript. Anyway, I'd still recommend encrypting the correct answers using one-way encryption, java's very easy to decompile.

Comment: `JButton.setEnabled( true );`?

Comment: Yes of course you can disable or enable JButtons via their `setEnabled(enabled)` method. The logic of when or how this gets called will depend on the structure of your program. Note that I hope that you're not adding a MouseListener to your JButton as that would not allow the button to be disabled. JButtons were built to use ActionListeners and Actions just for this reason -- so that they can in fact be disabled and respond to space bar clicks.

Answer (score 2):

There a number of ways this might be achieved, one of the simplest might be to simply disable the button(s) until the user enters what you want.

The (minor) problem with this is that it will require the user to press the "action" key (typically <kbd>Enter</kbd>) until the input can be validated.  Not a big deal, but its not always obvious to the user.

Another approach would be to use a `DocumentListener` to monitor for changes to the underlying `Document` and validate the input in real time.

This approach allows you to provide real time feedback to the user as they type.  It also allows the user to paste content into the field and have it validated as well, which is not done if you use a `KeyListener`.

[image: Make it so]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TestDoc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDoc();
    }

    public TestDoc() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;
        private JButton button;

        public TestPane() {
            button = new JButton("Make it so");
            button.setEnabled(false);
            field = new JTextField(10);
            field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    validateInput();
                }
            });
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(field, gbc);
            add(button, gbc);

            field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    validateInput();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    validateInput();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    validateInput();
                }
            });
        }

        public void validateInput() {
            String text = field.getText();
            if ("go".equals(text)) {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Have a look at [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details

Comment: can you please tell me why saying dos command prompt is a crime?

Comment: No idea, when did I say it?

Answer (score 1):

I just give you this example to give you an idea and start you up

**Code**:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");
        jb.setEnabled(false);
        JTextField jt = new JTextField(15);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(200, 100);
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        jf.setLayout(layout);
        jf.add(jb);
        jf.add(jt);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jt.addKeyListener((new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
                String text = textField.getText();
                textField.setText(text.toUpperCase());
                if(!textField.getText().isEmpty())
                    jb.setEnabled(true);
                else
                    jb.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }));

    }
}
```

**output**:

[image]

**Explanation**:
There are many ways to accomplish what you want. For example, Key Listener and Document Listener. 
The good practice is to use Document Listener because it is not depended on activities.

**Note**: there are other good ways to solve your issue but I thought this way is more easier for you to understand

**Take a look at this comment**

> A [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) would be better as that lets you react to any
>   changes to the text, whether or not they were triggered by a key press
>   (e.g. a paste from the clipboard), and you don't have to worry about
>   key presses that don't cause the text to change. –  Ian Roberts

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

**Using Document Listener Approach which is good practice and recommended**

Code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class DocumentListenerSample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");
        jb.setEnabled(false);
        JTextField jt = new JTextField(15);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(200, 100);
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        jf.setLayout(layout);
        jf.add(jb);
        jf.add(jt);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                printIt(documentEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                printIt(documentEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                printIt(documentEvent);
            }

            private void printIt(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
                Document source = documentEvent.getDocument();
                int length = source.getLength();
                if(length != 0)
                    jb.setEnabled(true);
                else
                    jb.setEnabled(false);
                  }
        };
        jt.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);

        jf.setSize(250, 150);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: A [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) would be better as that lets you react to any changes to the text, whether or not they were triggered by a key press (e.g. a paste from the clipboard), and you don't have to worry about key presses that don't cause the text to change.

Comment: @IanRoberts thank you for clearing me more, I saw that answer but I was not sure so I posted this one :) I think this way is good enough for novice people do not you agree?

Comment: `KeyListener`s on text components are considered a bad practice as it can lead to document mutation problems and doesn't take into consideration might happens in the user pastes content into the field

Comment: Yours is a very bad recommendation to use a KeyListener with a text component (edit: as I now see others have already told you). Just don't do this please. Please fix so I can get rid of the -1 vote.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank u for ur input but could plz tell why? show me some source and at the end what do I need to fix .:)

Comment: @MadProgrammer has already told you why it's a bad idea, and has posted a better answer, 1+ to it.

Comment: k so I'll add that approach to my answer. if u read my post, I mentioned there are other ways. madprogrammer said something without any resource to back him up. I never say he is wrong but I have been thought I should have some resources for my claim all the time.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels at least he can add an example to his post to show why key listener approach is not good

Comment: That's not Mad's responsibility since the OP doesn't even mention KeyListener. The responsibility of someone answering this question is to provide a good answer and to **take care not to give any misleading answers**, even if they're just "options".

Comment: Better, but myself, I'd prefer no KeyListener code.

Comment: Don't have time for chat, but also, assume that based on your code and recommendation the OP uses a KeyListener, then suppose the user clicks on the text field, right clicks with the mouse, and pastes in the correct word for the field. Your KeyListener code would fail outright while a DocumentListener would work with cut and paste and with key entry. End of story.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could either jbtn.setEnabled(false) until you had all your answers or (probably easier) keep an answer count accessible to your MouseClicked routine that simply ignores clicks until the questions are answered.