# Trying to make a JButton visible when a JTextField is tabbed out

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to use an action listener to set a button visible when something is in a text field.

The text field will only detect when enter is hit, it needs to also pick up on a tab out of the field. Am I missing something? Is it possible to do that in Swing?

Comment: Use a `DocumentListener` to monitor for changes to the text field and/or a `FocusListener` to monitor when the focus of the control changes. I would avoid hiding/showing elements this way and instead prefer to enable/disable the components, this way the UI doesn't "change layout" unexpectedly

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838674/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-jbutton-disabled-until-the-user-puts-in-a-specific-word/25839256#25839256)